# How to find supported video format?

Tags: android, video

Is there any way to detect the video format supported by an Android phone programaticaly?
When I am trying to play a .mp4 video one of the test phones shows the error "Sorry this video cannot played". In such situation I want to detect the supported video format and convert the .mp4 to that format.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Android Supported Media Formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) or for more clarification you can direct google the specification of your device.

http://www.gsmarena.com/ is one of very good site for viewing device specification

Comment: Thanks.But I want to detect it programaticaly.

Comment: Then you should mentioned that part in the question